# How to find subfields of a non-Galois field extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K/F$ be a finite field extension.

If $K/F$ is Galois then it is well known that there is a bijection
between subgroups of $Gal(K/F)$ and subfields of $K/F$.

Since finding subgroups of a finite group is always easy (at least
in the meaning that we can find every subgroup by brute-force or otherwise)
this gives a nice way of finding subfields and proving they are the
only ones.

What can we do in the case that $K/F$ is not a Galois extension ?
that is: How can I find all subfields of a non-Galois field extension
?

Comment: An easy answer to this would be to compute the Galois closure of $K/F$ and consider the subfields of the Galois closure which are in $K$. Would that work for you?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva - what if the extension is not separable ? this answer seems good for the cases of characteristic $0$ and for finite fields so it's very nice on but doesn't answer all of the problem. this is just a question of intrest, I don't need an application for something so any information is good. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Hm. I must say I assumed the extension was separable because I don't see very often non-separable extensions. =P

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva - http://www.quickmeme.com/meme/3rc44q/ :P

Comment: Very nice meme, I like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the inseparable case there is an idea for a substitute Galois correspondence due, I think, to Jacobson: instead of considering subgroups of the Galois group, we consider (restricted) Lie subalgebras of the Lie algebra of derivations. I don't know much about this approach, but "inseparable Galois theory" seems to be a good search term.

Answer (score 4):

An easy answer in the separable case to this would be to compute the Galois closure of K/F and consider the subfields of the Galois closure which are in K.

Hope that helps,